# How do I start learn Python for web

Tags: python

I have been learning Python for a while, and now I'd like to learn Python for the web; using Python as a back-end of a website.  Where and how do I start learning this?

Example usages are: connecting to databases, and retrieving and storing information from forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/), which is the most popular python web framework.  It has a lot of features, such as an ORM and a template language, but it's pretty easy to get started and can be very simple to use.

Comment: Thanks, any good tutorial or book you suggest for django?

Comment: I recommend the tutorial on the main website: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

The docs on the site are good. And there is the free Django book: http://www.djangobook.com/

Comment: @srisar:  Did you look at the Django site before asking?  It has a tutorial that seems to be really obvious.

Answer (score 4):

While using a full framework like [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/), [Pylons](http://pylonshq.com/) or [TurboGears](http://turbogears.org/) is nice, you could also check out the more light-weight approaches.

For instance:

- Werkzeug: http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/documentation/dev/tutorial.html
- web.py: http://webpy.org/
- Bottle: http://bottle.paws.de/

Comment: yea, this is kinda think i expected, light weight, good thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might also try:

- Tornado, which allows you to write pure python right into templates.

  - web2py is a good start as it doesn't requires installation or configuration,and has no dependencies, it's pretty simple to learn
    and use.
  - Another good option if you wanted to speed the learning process would be take a customized crash course in python with an expert. As an example:  https://www.hartmannsoftware.com/Training/Python?

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous frameworks for making websites in Python. Once you are familiar with Python and the general nature of websites which would include the knowledge of HTTP, HTML you can proceed by using any of the following to make websites using Python:

- Webapp2 - A simple framework to get you started with making websites and using this framework you can easily make websites and cloud services and host them on the Google App Engine service. Follow these links for more information on use and hosting: Welcome to webapp2!, Google App Engine
- Django - As Alex Remedios has mentioned Django is also a very popular and widely used MVC web framework for Python. It is very comprehensive and follows the MVC web design principles. Various hosting options are also available for the same. You can learn more about Django here - The Web framework for perfectionists with deadlines, The Django Book (for learning the use of Django)
- Flask - Flask is a simplistic framework for making webapplications and websites using Python. I do not extensive experience using it but from what I have read it is similar to Webapp2 in many ways but is not as comprehensive as Django. But, it is very easy to pickup and use. Flask (A Python Microframework)

As far as my knowledge goes these are the best ways to use Python in the web. To answer your second question, it is not implicitly possible to use Python in cohesion with HTML content like you would with PHP. However, there are libraries to do that too like the following:

1. Python Wiki - Digi Developer
2. Karrigell 3.1.1

If you are making extensive applications/websites the above two frameworks will pose major problems in doing simple tasks.

Answer (score 0):

there are numerous options for learning python for web. I learned python to access web data from courser.org, and the tutorial was very interesting. If you want to learn python for web then I suggest you to learn python to access web data in courser.org

you can also learn python for everybody which is a specialization course with 5 courses in which each and every thing about python is given.

The fun part of courser.org is that they provide assignments with due dates which means you have to complete an assessment of each week in that week itself. They also provide quiz. You have to pass all the assignments and quizzes to get the certificate which is very easy, you can easily complete the assessment and quizzes.